# SharePoint: Auto open/exe pptx or doc files from centralised location to different monitors

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

My requirements are given below:

1. I want to keep my files in a centralized location
2. I can schedule a time to open ppt/doc to different monitors.
3. On the scheduled time file should open automatically on the monitors.

I am new to SharePoint technology. Is this feasible in SharePoint?
Thanks

Comment: I think your requirement is unrelated to SharePoint? I mean, what would change for any other location / file type? Isn't it your operating system / window manager that defines on which monitor to open what? SharePoint is a server-side software (runs on server, like Google Docs for example) so it seems that it can't really open anything on your client?

Comment: Could you please suggest any other technology that can meet my requirements?

Comment: In windows, you could use task scheduler maybe (in case you are using windows)?